# Need Help : Python Filepaths

Tags: python, filepath

I have an AI bot that when it is asked to, it opens an application. But because computers are different the file path doesn't work on all computer as they are different, so i am trying to figure a way to be able to open them on both computers without changing the code, if the file paths are different. This is what I've got so far:

```
elif inp=="Word" or inp=="word":
    subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE"])
```

I am also trying to figure out if there is a way to open a shortcut, as the file path is the same
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Word 2016

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If application can change in several executions, try to pass it as arg in command line. If application is the same, try to look it up in the HD.

Answer (score 0):

In python you need to use the OS primitive if you want to manipulate path. A quick example from what you provided:

```
os.path.join("Microsoft Office","root","Office16")
```

Assuming that your program is started from "C:\Program Files (x86)", it will build the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\"

You have the doc there:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html